# Javascript initialize functions by "page"

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

Maybe iam a bit confus but .. how do you handle the following case:

Webapplication (no PHP just JS/HTMLCSS) with a lot of Javascript (JQuery).
I have one large File called "application.js" wich is included in every page.

I want to fire different functions on different pages like:

http://mysite.de/index is called fire: index.init();

http://mysite.de/about is called fire: about.init();

I think it something like the Controller from MVC eh? My solutions was like using switch and an stativ "var = pageName" on every page, but i am sure there is an better way? Or is it an Design problem?

I know about libs like Require.js, but thats to much for my case.

To define the question a bit more concret: Is this an "good" way to implement JS? I know i can access the the windows.location or identify by title or what ever!

Comment: What about just looking at `window.location`?  Or some sort of class on the `<html>` or `<body>` tag?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but it sounds like you could create an object with functions related to each page, and then execute `pageFunctions[location.pathname].init()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
index.init();
</script>
```

In the index page? And then call a different function on each page?

I understand a dynamic way would be cool, but sometimes you can over engineer something this simple.

Comment: This "Solution" is something i was not thinking about, thanks :-)

Comment: No problem, sometimes a simplistic approach is better than reinventing the wheel!

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `document.URL` and build a case statement around it.

```
var url = document.URL;
switch (url) {
case "http://mysite.de/index":
  index.init();
  break;
case "http://mysite.de/about":
  about.init();
  break;
}
```

Or you could use something like backbone.js if this starts to get complex.